# Python - local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I am relatively new to programming and I am suffering from what appears to be a simple problem.

Here's the snippet that is causing the problem (it is part of this larger function: http://pastebin.com/2apwWsEv):

```
for i in range(4,12):                       # remove nulls
    if not row[i]:
        row[i] = False
    if row[i] and (i % 2):                          # odd rows (time)
        print row[i]
        time = row[i].split(':')
        row[i] = int(time[0]) * 3600 + int(time[1]) * 60 + int(time[2])
```

**Output:**

```
row[i] = int(time[0]) * 3600 + int(time[1]) * 60 + int(time[2])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment
```

It seems I assigned `time` the value of `row[i].split(':')`, so I do not understand where the error is.

I tried changing around the second `if` statement (to a more conventional `elif`, etc) but that did not change the error.

*(The time field, of the csv data, is in the format of hh:mm:ss and I am trying to convert it to seconds.)*

Can someone please explain how `time` is being used before it is assigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pastebin, the line `row[i] = int(...` is indented using four spaces and four tabs. Even though the line appears to have the same indentation as the line prior to it, it's actually indented one less when interpreted by Python.

Don't intermix tabs and spaces; use only one or the other. The prevailing style is to use only spaces.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please don't use a name of a libray for the name of a variable. 'time' is definitly a libray.
2. If you want to use global variables in a function (and don't get the 'referenced before assignment'-error ;-) ) write

`global name_of_variable`

in your code at the beginning of the function (see [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them))